# How many tags for QGIS model building?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently these tags related to QGIS model building:

- [qgis-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-modeler) (160 questions) with a tag wiki excerpt (and tag wiki):

> An application of QGIS used to develop models utilizing a large
>   variety of powerful Geoprocessing tools via a GUI.

- [graphical-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-modeler) (8 questions) with no tag wiki excerpt (or tag wiki)

Are both/more needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem all 8 questions for [graphical-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-modeler) use QGIS as the software in which case I would vote for replacing them with [qgis-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-modeler).

Personally, I think [graphical-modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-modeler) should be removed and any GIS software with a model-building function should have its own tag (e.g. *someGIS-modeler*).

Comment: With 6/0 up/down on this answer and 1/1 (net 0) on the other I have proceeded to make [tag:graphical-modeler] a synonym of [tag:qgis-modeler].

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `graphical-modeler` to cover more than just QGis but it could certainly use a wiki etc.

Comment: Do you think [tag:graphical-modeler] should only be used for model building questions other than those already tagged [tag:qgis-modeler] or [tag:modelbuilder]?

Comment: I'm a cli guy but I would be happy to see it on any modelling question with a graphical interface